# Spring WebFlow - cancel request

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

The scenario is this:

a have some view-states. 
when an object in my conversationScope is in a certain state (e.g. not null) i want to prevent that the user can go back.
by going back i mean: ether press the browser back button or manipulate the execution-parameter.

one way of "preventing" would be ignoring the request.

i have tried to implement a `FlowExecutionListenerAdapter` but this has only access to the `requestContext`, `view` and `viewState`

so the question is:
what and how is the best way to to this?
Handler, Listener or Interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay i solved it pretty dirty, but i solved it:

i wrote a `FlowExecutionListenerAdapter` implementation, which throws an `Exception` in the  `resuming` phase if the criterias match.

```
@Override
public void resuming(RequestContext context)
{
    if (!backwardNavigation)
    {
        if (!context.getFlowExecutionContext().getActiveSession().getState().getId()
                .equals(attributeConfigurer.getFinishViewState()))
        {
            throw new ConfirmationFinishRedirectException();
        }

    }
}
```

and i catch the exception with a transition in the state where it is thrown.

```
<transition on-exception="example.ConfirmationFinishRedirectException" to="finishState" bind="false" validate="false" history="discard"/>
```

i got the idea for this solution from this site: [SpringForum - Thread: FlowExecutionListener - how to intercept and redirect user](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?103617-FlowExecutionListener-how-to-intercept-and-redirect-user)

Answer (score 0):

what about setting `history="discard"` on your transistion?

Comment: i tried that before my post. 
discard just deletes the last snapshot and invalidate deletes all snapshots of the excution. so going back throws an exception

Comment: You did say "prevent", which these approaches do. I understand why you prefer your solution, but given what was posted in the question, I think it's unfair to downvote this answer (whoever did that). (Note, it's not my answer.)